# Is it possible view the MAC address from the hard drive one an old computer?

Tags: windows, internet, ip, windows-registry, mac-address

I need to see the MAC address on a system from an old computer.

I tried a lot of things in  Event Viewer and also in the Regedit but I  can’t seem to find it.

Is there any way to do this? Is this even possible to do?

Comment: What you're asking may not be possible, unless Windows or some software is caching this information. MAC address is typically stored in permanent memory of a network adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and give the command `ipconfig /all`
That will give information, including mac-addresses, for all network interfaces. Even if they have no actual connection. (It is possible the mac-address is listed under the name "hardware address".)

If you only have the harddisk, but not the original system (or the system doesn't work anymore for some reason), things get far more complicated.
You need to load the system registry hive into regedit on another machine and locate the foldertree `ControlSet001\Control\Class`.
In that folder-tree search for registry keys pairs called `bimacaddres_h` and `bimacaddres_l`.
They always appear in pairs and contain the vendor part (upper 24 bits) in the _h key and the device part (lower 24 bits) in the _l key.
You will probably find several of these pairs. One of them will be the one you are looking for. (The vendor part will give an indication which network interface of the original machine it was.)

Comment: Sorry for being noob, didn't understand what should I do after entering the ControlSet001\Control\Class, I can only see a lot of folders with charters..can you add a screenshot for me? http://prntscr.com/107qkd8

Comment: @Asaf0808 you use the find function to look for the keys. They are somewhere within all those subfolders with numerical names.